# How to get my categories with date in xAxis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts

I've finally got my step-chart showing some results, but now I want to style it to my needs.

My code is as follow:

```
$(function () {
    $('#urvalResultIntervalDevelopmentGraf').highcharts('StockChart',{
        title: {
            text: 'Chart'
        },
        rangeSelector : {
            enabled: false
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            categories: ['2012-08-10', '2012-09-17', '2013-09-26', '2014-07-01', '2014-09-01', '2014-09-23'],
            gridLineWidth:0
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Loss'
            },
            opposite: false,
            gridLineWidth:0
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ':-'
        },
        series: [
            {name:'Gustafsson',step:true,data:[[1344549600,-119],[1347832800,-99],[1380146400,-48],[1404165600,-3],[1409522400,-74],[1411423200,-25]]},
        ],
    });
});
```

How do I get my categories to show on the xAxis?
I'm guessing it cant match my dates (yyyy-mm-dd) to the ones in the data (timestamp), but I dont know how to handle it.

My jsfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/skorpion/akkxmke8/61/

Answer (score 2):

You can't, like in [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes): you can use categories or datetime xAxis. If you want specific format, then simply use [xAxis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter).